# Foundation Modal does no work with custom back_text

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

The modal function does not work when I pass parameters to custom text_back of the nav.

```
 $(document).foundation('topbar', {

    custom_back_text: true,
    back_text: 'Atraz'

});
```

Only when i use the default script, this works, but i need to change the back_text, thanks

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
 </script>
```